# SQLite search by name, show sum result in textfield

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a code that would give me the sum of a column in  a database, i have done the crud, but now i would like to do a search by a the name of a column and show the sum of all the records(that have the same name) and show in a textfield.
the following is my DatabasdeHandler:

```
    public Cursor getSingleDespesaSum(String date) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int sum = 0;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "select sum(valor)  from despesas WHERE data = ?", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            sum = cursor.getInt(0);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

And this is my activity;

```
btGetSum.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                dia = (String) spinDia.getSelectedItem();
                mes = (String) spinMes.getSelectedItem();
                ano = (String) spinAno.getSelectedItem();
                String dataSendTo = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;

                dbhelper.getSingleDespesaSum(dataSendTo); //missing code

            } catch (Exception erro) {
                mensagemExibir("Erro Ao Buscar", "" + erro.getMessage());
            }



        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Content Providers are the way to go, don't access your database directly like this.

But... to answer your current question:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
int sum = 0;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
        "select value from table WHERE date= ?", null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
        //Increment your counter
        sum += cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("value");
};
```

Comment: thanks, as soon as possible i'll try it(My english is not quite a thing, i'm brazilian)...

Comment: I'm thinking, i don't know if i was clear, i want not the sum of how many records i have with that specific name, i want the sum of the values of all that records(all that columns, in this case the column value) with that specific name.Just in case i was not clear. thanks

Comment: ok, i want to get in a textfield, the sum of the values in the column "value", where the column "date" is equal to "the date i send to the query from the activity"